# Override of Zend_View_Helper not being picked up in Zend_Layout

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view, zend-layout

### TL;DR: In ZF1, after registering a custom prefix in application.ini, the Zend_View_Helper_* namespace takes precedence over my own despite working correctly in regular views.

- Created an override of `Zend_View_Helper_Url`, called `App_View_Helper_Url`.
- Placed the file in `APPPLICATION_PATH/library/App/View/Helper/Url.php`
- Registered the namespace via application.ini: `resources.view.helperPath.App_View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/library/App/View/Helper"`

This works. In my Views, the custom URL helper is now being called. However, in template views, the additional namespace doesn't seem to take hold. I verified this by running this snippet: `<?php var_dump(get_class($this->getHelper('url'))); ?>`

- index.phtml: `App_View_Helper_Url`
- layout.phtml: `Zend_View_Helper_Url`

I've tried resolving this by explicitly setting the Layout view to the View resource being bootstrapped - this did not work.

```
$this->getResource('layout')->setView($this->getResource('view'));
```

In the end I fixed it by fixing doing the following in the Bootstrap:

```
$view = $layout->getView();
$view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/library/App/View/Helper', 'App_View_Helper');
```

This solution is not very satisfying as I'm now defining the same helper path twice, leading to potential breakage down the line. So while I have a workaround, I'd prefer to understand how/where to configure the Zend_View instance used by Zend_Layout correctly, preferably through application.ini.